# Unable to fetch property from prototype of function that returns function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, ecmascript-5

*Greet* is a simple function that returns a *function* as an output.

We added `dev` to the prototype of the *greet function* to show developer's name.

```js
function greet() {
    function hello(name) {
        console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
    }
    return {hello}
}

greet.prototype.dev = "Dev name";

let greetObj = new greet();

console.log(greetObj.dev) // Displays as undefined.
```

My expectation was that `greetObj.dev` or any other object created from the *greet function* will display the `dev` property defined in the `greet prototype` but instead we are getting `undefined`.

Can anyone please help where I am going wrong here?

Comment: If you intend for `greet` to be a constructor, it should not return anything

Comment: You are returning a brand new object which only contain a property `hello`. And you are adding `dev` property on `greet`. Both are different object and `greet` is not `prototype` of `greetObj`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to assign the value to `this` in constructor function. You don't have to return `anything`. JS will return an object will all property assign to that object

```js
function greet() {
  function hello(name) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
  }
  this.hello = hello;
}

greet.prototype.dev = "Dev name";

let greetObj = new greet();
console.log(greetObj.dev);
```

**`Best Practice`**

But this is not a best practice to attach a function in the constructor function. It will just add `hello` function to all objects which unnecessarily create multiple copy per object, which you shouldn't do that.

You should ideally attach that function to its `prototype` as:

```js
function greet() {}

function hello(name) {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
}

greet.prototype.hello = hello;
greet.prototype.dev = "Dev name";

let greetObj = new greet();
console.log(greetObj.dev);
greetObj.hello("developer");
```